# 2 подсети 2 сервера 1 свич

Tags: windows, подсети, сеть

Подскажите, правильно я размышляюБыла одна большая сеть, теперь нужно ее разделить на 2 езависимые, перетыягивать кабеля желания нет

Итого что предпологаю:

Создать 2 подсети С1 и С2

На каждом сервере сделать общедоступным подключение WAN (раздать интернет для своей подсети)

---

настройки С1

С1Сервер -

IP: 192.168.1.1

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Нак лиентах сети C1 настройки должны быть статическми (DHCP не используем)

IP:  192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Шлюз: 192.168.1.1

DNS: 192.168.1.1

---

С2Сервер -

IP: 192.168.2.1

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Нак лиентах сети C2 настройки должны быть статическми (DHCP не используем)

IP:  192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.254

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Шлюз: 192.168.2.1

DNS: 192.168.2.1

Желаемый результат -  2 подсети работают по одной разводке кабелей но не видят машин друг друга и используют интернет каждая с своего сервера.

Выйдет так? Какие могут быть проблемы , как избежать.

[План сети](http://s40.radikal.ru/i087/1306/08/a4b44698737f.png)

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если свитч управляемый - то лучше использовать VLAN'ы. Изоляция на втором уровне (канальном) на порядок лучше чем на третьем (сетевом) по многим причинам (если интересно - могу некоторые перечислить). Ещё один вариант - traffic segmentation (в терминологии D-LINK), хотя VLAN - более удачное и расширяемое решение(можно добавлять свитчи в сеть сохраняя её логическое разделение), тем более что сети вы изолируете полностью. Если нужна будет связь между сетями, то при сегментировании VLAN'ами придётся немного поколдовать с настройками железок или с их составом.В Вашем варианте - связи по IP между машинами не будет, но кучи мусорного и вирусного трафика будут общей проблемой обеих подсетей.

Answer (score 0):

все будет работать и при таких настройках. Причем вполне сносно, но только при не большом количестве юзерей.Если позволяет железо (стоит Циско или hp) то используй однозначны Vlanы. А если стоят что то из разряда "тупых Д-линков то даже и не морочься, делай свои настройки и будь готов к тормозам при большой нагрузке.Если нужна связи между сетями, то на серверах в интерфейсах пропиши вторичным ip, IP из второй подсети.

Пример:

настройки С1

С1Сервер -

IP: 192.168.1.1 вторичны ip 192.168.2.2

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Нак лиентах сети C1 настройки должны быть статическми (DHCP не используем)

IP: 192.168.1.3 - 192.168.1.254

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Шлюз: пусто (сервер сам шлюз этой подсети)

DNS: не нужноВторой интерфейс сервера соответственно в соответствии с настройками провайдера/роутера, только с разрешенным общим доступом.

С2Сервер -

IP: 192.168.2.1вторичный 192.168.1.1

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Нак лиентах сети C2 настройки должны быть статическми (DHCP не используем)

IP: 192.168.2.3 - 192.168.2.254

Маска: 255.255.255.0

Шлюз: пусто (сервер сам шлюз этой подсети)

DNS: пустоВторой интерфейс аналогично первому серверу.

Comment: Спасибо! В сети 25 ПК, не думаю что сильно будут юзеры загружать сеть.  А по поводу видимости сетей - на заметку себе взял:)

Comment: @Ярослав Романенко, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png